# spark dataframe save to SQL table with auto increment column

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have the following table in db

```
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| VERSION        | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| measurement_id | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| day            | timestamp  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hour           | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| hour_timestamp | timestamp  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value          | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to save spark dataframe that holds multiple rows that have the following case class structure:

```
case class Record(val id : Int,
                  val VERSION : Int,
                  val user_id : Int,
                  val measurement_id : Int,
                  val day : Timestamp,
                  val hour : Int,
                  val hour_timestamp : Timestamp,
                  val value : Long  )
```

When I'm trying to save the dataframe to my sql through jdbc driver using:

```
dataFrame.insertIntoJDBC(...)
```

I get a primary key violation error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

I tried to set id=0 as the default value of all the rows and also tried to remove the id field from the case class, neither worked.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Tomer

Comment: Are you sure that the only duplicate is the first record?

Answer (score 5):

Found it.
I had a sql <-> java column type issue.
According to: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html

bigint sql columns should be represented as Long in java.
After I've changed my case class to:

```
case class Record(val id: Long,
                  val VERSION : Long,
                  val user_id : Long,
                  val measurement_id : Long,
                  val day : Timestamp,
                  val hour : Int,
                  val hour_timestamp : Timestamp,
                  val value : Long  )
```

And set a id=0 for all the records in the dataframe it worked.
Thanks